# Volume of a rotated ellipse by x=y

Tags: calculus, volume, centroid

I'm calculating a volume of a rotated ellipse by the line $x=y$ using Pappus Theorem, the ellipse has an equation of :
$$(9x^2/16)+(36y^2/25)=1$$
Using Pappus Theorem, I can just plug in the length of centroid (d) to $x=y$ and area(A) to
$$V = 2pi*dA$$
What I've been struggling for is to find the centroid, do I rotate the area under the line? if so, then how can I find the centroid for the area under the line? I've tried using the integration ones but I got $x ~ 0.9$ and that doesn't really makes sense.

Comment: Please share your working. What was your set up for the integral to find centroid?

Comment: I used the integral from -4/3 to 4/3 of $x(x-(5/6)*(1-9x^2/16))$ over the area under the curve which is -4/3 to 4/3 of $(x-(5/6)*(1-9x^2/16))$

Comment: But the rotation is around $y = x$. My suggestion would be to use rotation of coordinate axes by $45^0$ counterclockwise (or clockwise) so major axis of ellipse is along $y = x$ (or $y = -x$) and axis of rotation is y-axis (or x-axis). Then check the limits of $y$ for which the radius to the left is greater than the right and the limits for which the radius to the right is greater than the left.

Comment: Be careful about overlap.